# Looping of the query from database

Tags: java, loops, csv

I am writing the query from database into a CSV file using Java. How do I do so that I could loop the result from query so that it is displayed row by row in the CSV file. Below are the snippet of my code.

```
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();

sb.append(reportBO.projectList(this.getSearchBean());
sb,append(',');
sb.append('\n');
```

Let say my query would be

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECT
```

Below are my expected outcome.
[image]

Comment: Where is the code for writing to csv file?

Comment: Could you please give data example that you query from DB and what should it be in CSV file, how it would be displayed ?

Comment: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));                                                                                                  pw.write(sb.toString());  ...this is how i write into CSV file and I have edited the quetions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I solve my solution. Hope it helps someone. Thanks all for helping..

```
for (int i = 0; i < ((List<BaseDTOInf>) getProjectList(searchBean)).size();i++) {

                BaseDTO list = (BaseDTO) getProjectList(searchBean).get(i);
                list.getDataMap().get("A");
                list.getDataMap().get("B");
                list.getDataMap().get("C");
                list.getDataMap().get("D");
                list.getDataMap().get("E");
                list.getDataMap().get("F");

                sb.append(list.getDataMap().get("A"));
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(list.getDataMap().get("B"));
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(list.getDataMap().get("C"));
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(list.getDataMap().get("D"));
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(list.getDataMap().get("E"));
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append('\n');

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop the result set as mentioned below and write it into the file,

```
    while (rs.next()){
         sb.append(rs.getString(<ColumnName1>));
         sb.append(',');
         sb.append(rs.getString(<ColumnName2>));
         sb.append(',');
         sb.append(rs.getString(<ColumnName3>));
         sb.append('\n');
    }
```

If you are populating data into `StringBuffer` then make sure to write it into the file in regular interval (e.g every 1000 rows). Else you might get `OutOfMemoryException` if result contains huge number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CSV writer to handle this properly. Values can have commas, quotes, newlines and must be properly escaped.

From your code, it seems you are trying to write beans instead of getting stuff straight from the ResultSet. In this case, you can try[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial):

```
//creates a configuration object that allows you to determine how to 
//format your CSV output, among many other things. Check the tutorial.
CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();

//Configures the parser to process input objects using the BeanWriterProcessor. 
//This reads the data from your java beans. In this case the type is "TestBean"
//but in yours it seems that would be something like "SearchBean".
settings.setRowWriterProcessor(new BeanWriterProcessor<TestBean>(TestBean.class));

//Defines the headers to print out to the output. My "TestBean" class has the 
//following fields. Adjust this to reflect the fields in your "SearchBean"
settings.setHeaders("amount", "pending", "date", "quantity", "comments");

// Creates a CsvWriter with the settings above
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/path/to/file.csv")), settings);

//Loads the beans from the database. 
//The "loadBeanList" method is something you should implement. 
List<TestBean> beansToPersist = loadBeanList();

//With a list of beans loaded from the database, you can simply call this 
//and write everything into your CSV file. You can also write beans one by one.
writer.processRecordsAndClose(beansToPersist);
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: Hi..thanks for pointing out my mistakes :) But could you explain abit more on your solution cause I don't really understand it. Thanks in advance. @JeronimoBackes